# I was trying to build an django project, it shows ```got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked'```

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, docker-compose

The project when I previously build on my laptop it works but when I was trying to build this project on my pc it shows docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: HTTPConnection.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked'.

**My docker-compose.yml file looks like**

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.0-alpine3.14
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - korean_mbc_appointment:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: ./
    restart: always
    command: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/code
    expose:
      - 421
#    ports:
#      - "420:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./static:/code/static
      - ./media:/code/media
    ports:
      - "420:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
volumes:
  korean_mbc_appointment:
```

**The issue when I was trying to build the project looks like**

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 602, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 496, in _make_request
    conn.request(
TypeError: HTTPConnection.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
    return get_project(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
    client = get_client(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
    client = APIClient(use_ssh_client=not use_paramiko_ssh, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: HTTPConnection.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chunked'
```

Comment: Which Docker version are you using and which platform/cli are you using?

Comment: I am using  docker version ```Docker version 24.0.4, build 3713ee1``` and docker-compose version ```docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown```

Comment: Are you on Aws (or other cloud provider) or on premise? If you are on cloud provider, are you using their cli?

Comment: I use contabo VPS.
I was trying to build the project on my VPS using CLI and the above issue occurred.

Comment: it looks like compatibility issue to me 

I used `docker compose up`  (without -) and it worked for me 

my docker compose version given me `Docker Compose version v2.21.0` 

try installing this new version of docker compose and then use it likewise

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when I was trying to run the `docker-compose up` command, but my user wasn't added to the `docker` group.

I solved it by running `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` first.